# Dirac Delta function to solve PDE in the sense of distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

For each Borel set $A$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, denote Dirac measure centered at $x$ as
\begin{equation}
\delta_x(A)=\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if } x\in A \\ 0 & \mbox{ otherwise}. \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Alternatively, we can think $\delta_x$ in the sense of distribution defined by
\begin{equation}
<\delta_x,\phi> = \phi(x).
\end{equation}
I want to show that for $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $u(x,t):=\delta_{x-ct}$ solves the PDE
\begin{equation}
u_t+c\cdot Du = 0 \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^{n+1}
\end{equation}
in the sense of distribution.

I tried
\begin{equation}
<u_t, \phi> = <D_t\delta_{x-ct}, \phi> = -<\delta_{x-ct}, D_t\phi>=-\phi(x-ct)(-c)
\end{equation}
I am not sure about the last equality because when $c$ is a vector, $<u_t,\phi>$ is a vector? Should it be a scalar instead?

What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the chain rule in the last step. Putting in some extra parentheses for emphasis, you have:

$$D_t (\phi(x-ct)) = (\nabla \phi)(x-ct) \cdot (-c)$$

which is a scalar.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, $c$ is a vector (the velocity vector underlying the transport).

Comment: I see. Is it the same thing for $x$-derivative? It looks like I only have $\nabla\phi(x-ct)$

Comment: @dh87 The $x$ derivative is already a vector, and then taking the dot product with $c$ recovers a scalar again. But I think I may have lost track of a minus sign somewhere.

Comment: For the second term, do we have $<c\cdot Du, \phi> = c\cdot <Du, \phi>$?

Comment: @dh87 Sure; this is basically just factoring out a constant from an integral. (And I think I see that I didn't lose a minus sign, we just *gain* another minus sign when we move the derivative from $u$ to $\phi$ in the second term.)

Comment: Does that mean $<Du,\phi>$ is a vector? I am a bit confused because I learned in class it is a scalar.

Comment: @dh87 Yes. Essentially, $u$ is a "scalar-valued" distribution so $Du$ is a "vector-valued" distribution. You may be mixing up the distribution-function pairing notation with the inner product notation.